Какой план для изучения профессии "Белый хакер"?
Есть мечта, стать специалистом в профессии "Белый хакер", буквально знать всё, но я не знаю с чего начать, что учить, какой план/шаблон изучения.
Если в языках программирования довольно легко - виден общий шаблон изучения, то в ИБ для меня не так всё просто, я не вижу. Если и начинаю что-то учить, то сразу падаю в сомнения, "то ли я учу?" и "с того ли я начал?".
Пожалуйста, напишите план изучения ИБ. Отрасли ИБ, с чего начать. Может полезные сайты, книги, которые помогут мне.

1, 2

Особенность знаний, необходимых хакеру — широкий спектр дисциплин.
То что строго рекомендуется знать любому хакеру это основы программирования (чем глубже, тем лучше), отлично разбираться в сетевых технологиях (я имею ввиду нужно не просто представлять как устроен интернет, а твёрдо знать теоретические основы дисциплины «Сети и телекоммуникации»).
Начать советую с этого, это пригодится в любом случае. Чем глубже знания, тем лучше.
Дальше уже вопрос конкретной специализации. Например, бывают хакеры которые занимаются разработкой криптографической защиты программ, бывают например те, которые защищают информационные сети предприятий, ну и так далее.
После того как вы определитесь со специализацией, я уверен ответ в какую сторону продолжать придёт сам собой.
А вообще, желающих "вкатиться в ИБ" сейчас множество, но на мой взгляд это не то, чему можно научиться. Быть настоящим хакером это призвание — нужно иметь стремление и желание разбираться как устроена та или иная технология, когда есть желание, изучение нового не становится проблемой. А когда не знаешь за что браться, чтобы делать не знаешь что — разумеется ничего и не получится, только время зря потратишь.
